# how to access the event object and form data (method...) on form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, events, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I'm trying to upgrade a javascript site to a Jquery Mobile site. I need to preventDefault a form submission to run my validation routine and fire an ajax form submission.

I have this:

HTML

```
<form name="LoginForm" id="LoginForm" action="some.html" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" onClick="routine('true')" />
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
function rountine(isit){
   if(isit == "true"){
      document.LoginForm.action = "some.html"; 
      }
   console("rountine triggered");

   $("#LoginForm").submit(function(event, data){
       console.log("submission triggered");
       console.log(event);
       console.log(data);
       event.preventDefault();  
       });
 };
```

**Question:**
I'm only getting the first console message. The form is not submitted, but nothing else shows up on the console. What am I doing wrong? Also do I need to re-specify *action* or can I omit it in the HTML part and maybe set it dynamically from within my rountine function?

Thanks for helP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line :

```
$("#LoginForm").submit(function(event, data){
```

Is setting up an event handler for submitting of the form ... see http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Do it this way :

```
<form name="LoginForm" id="LoginForm" action="some.html" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#LoginForm").submit(function(event){
     // actions you want to perform on the form submitting
     if(isit == "true"){
        document.LoginForm.action = "some.html"; 
     }
     console("rountine triggered");
     console.log("submission triggered");
     console.log(event); // event is an object - dont expect much in the console
     event.preventDefault();  
   });
});
```

This will setup the submit listener and the code within the function will be executed on submit - `event.preventDefault();` will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: sounds good. Any idea how I can get the "true" value from onClick="routine('true')" into the equation?

Comment: use a hidden text field to store a value and get the value using `$('#idofhiddenfield').val()`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is adding an handler to an event, not executing it.
So once you add this handler, you should see all other console message too.

```
$("#LoginForm").submit(function() {
  .. // This will get executed when submit is pressed
});
```

To call the submit event, call `$("#LoginForm").submit()` with no arguments, which fires the submit event.